# Search For business locations in google Map API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps-api-3

HI,
I'm trying to figure out which service and parameters to use to return a list of business addresses and location points (lat/lngs) near a given city.  I need results for a query like "caribou coffee,chapel hil" .  I tried using the Geocode service (`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=caribou%20+coffee,+chapel%20+hil&sensor=false`) 
response:-

```
-<GeocodeResponse>
<status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Is this the correct API for this type of request? or what should I do to make it like google maps because when I type in google maps caribou coffee, chapel hil I get certain places corrsponding to that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this Google Places API- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Karthikeyan no this will not work because places api needs latitude and longitude and that I dont have , I only have the business name.

Comment: You have the lat/lng of the city.  You can use that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Google Local Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/jsondevguide.html), try making this string into a URL (after making a query and setting numberOfResults with max of 8):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&mrt=localonly&q=%@&rsz=%@&start=0",query,numberOfResults]]
```

I also published some simple iOS classes that use Google's Local Search API to easily get location information about places in a map region via a name and/or address search, if you're interested.  There are [detailed instructions here](http://www.totagogo.com/2011/02/08/google-local-search-ios-code/), and [the GitHub repository is here](https://github.com/vvanhee/Google-Local-Search-iOS).

Alternatively, you could use the relatively new [SimpleGeo Places](https://simplegeo.com/).

Finally, it also looks like the [Google Place API will do what you want with the info contained here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html), but it requires a few queries to get the info (first get a list of predictions, then use the keys obtained to get more detailed info including location) and has fairly strict limits on (free) API usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `v2 API` instead of v3, and change the query to search by **`ZIP`** instead of `local`. Also there is a curious issue in that you will get empty results if your clicking on a direct link, so Iv'e removed the direct link. Copy and Paste will work.

direct link:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?q=caribou+coffee,27514&sensor=false&output=xml

Copy and Paste link:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/geo?q=caribou+coffee,27514&sensor=false&output=xml

Comment: @ llya Berelson but I dont have zip code the user only enters business name then what I should do?

Comment: @Gypsa this should help [zip codes](http://www.census.gov/tiger/tms/gazetteer/zips.txt)